# Change the order of a table on date, R

Tags: r, sorting, date, dataframe

I'm trying to order a table by month. The problem is when I make a table from my dataset the names of the table become characters and it sorts the months in alphabetical order like this:

```
apr-2013 aug-2013 feb-2013 jan-2013 jul-2013 jun-2013 mei-2013 mrt-2013 nov-2013 okt-2013 sep-2013  
     203      272      314      243      292      263      283      196       22      226      131
```

and with sort(mytable) it sorts on its value and not on month. Is there any way that it sorts on date?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide an [mcve] there. This will make it much easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The strings from the column names can be converted to a year-month format using "yearmon" from the "zoo" library and you can use this to rearrange the columns:

```
library(zoo)
ordered_data <- mytable[,order(factor(as.yearmon(colnames(mytable), 
                                                 format='%b-%Y')))]
```